# Create base64 string in pdfKit

Tags: javascript, node.js, base64, pdfkit

How to get base64 string instead the blob pdf encoding? My approach does not work and I get the pdf blob in frontend instead base64.

```
  const pdfName = "cv123.pdf";
  const pdfPath = path.join('data', pdfName)
  const pdfDoc = new PDFDocument();
  pdfDoc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(pdfPath, {encoding: "base64"}));
  pdfDoc.pipe(res)
  pdfDoc.text("TEST").fontSize(20)
  pdfDoc.end();
```

Comment: @KJ The problem is in binary transfer that I lose PDF content, using base64 encoding everything works.

Comment: I have created the solution for the problem. Yes I spent hours to handle it by binary data. I set the headers in frontend like responseType: "blob", I createUrlObject from the blob and downloaded the PDF but the problem was that backend sent the i.e 2 pages of PDF, but this PDF was without content. I also took the blob from frontend and just created PDF outside the website to check if the blob is correct and It was not correct, it was without text.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to create read stream from the created PDF by the PDFkit, it works

```
const pdfName = `cv123${orderId}.pdf`;
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
  res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", `attachment; filename=${pdfName}`);
  const pdfPath = path.join("data", pdfName);
  const pdfStream = fs.createWriteStream(pdfPath);
  const pdfDoc = new PDFDocument();
  const writeStream = pdfDoc.pipe(pdfStream);
  pdfDoc.fontSize(25).text(`Order ${orderId}`);
  pdfDoc.fontSize(13).text(`User ${orderUser.name}`);

  pdfDoc.end();
  writeStream.on("finish", () => {
    const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(pdfPath, { encoding: "base64" });
    fileStream.on("data", (chunk: Buffer) => {
      res.write(chunk);
    });
    fileStream.on("end", () => {
      fs.unlink(pdfPath, () => {
        res.end();
      });
    });
  });
```